# Shouldn't recording electrode have as low resistance as possible?

Tags: electrophysiology

Following quote is from [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-unit_recording) wikipedia page on single unit recording.

> Intracellular single unit recordings require electrodes be inserted through the cell membrane to record from within the cell. Glass micropipettes or metal electrodes may be used for intracellular single unit recordings, but glass micropipettes are preferred because their high input resistance allows more precise recordings for measurement of resting potentials.

How high input resistance helps better recordings? Shouldn't recording electrode have as low resistance as possible?

Comment: Can you please offer your proposal for the situation? Do you know which variables are relevant there? What is your measurement setting?

Comment: Could it be that you mean impedance instead of resistance? It is one of the electrical properties that is the least understood by biologists (like me) and in the biological community there are lots of myths and rumors about whether impedance should be high or low. This might help: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/21787/why-is-high-input-impedance-good or this: https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-influence-of-electrode-impedance-on-EEG-data-recording (though it refers to EEG)

Answer (score 2):

For accurate measurement of the membrane potential, it is crucial to have as little current flow through the measurement device as possible. Otherwise, the equilibrium of leak channels that generates the resting potential would be disturbed. See diagram and text from *Axon Guide 3rd edition* below:

[image]